# Write a program to find max sum of K size window in n*m matrix traversing in 8 possible directions linearly

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, sliding-window

I recently gave interview at a company and was rejected in final round having only one problem.

**The interviewer stated a 2D-array of n*m length. We can traverse left right top down as well as both diagonally. A fixed window k was provided to find maximum sum of 1d array window traversing any of the way.**

**The array is not sorted and doesn't have any pattern. No overlapping/rolling is possible at edges.**

**1<=n,m<=10^5**

```
Example:- 2 3 4 5 2
          3 1 8 9 9
          4 4 3 2 8 
          3 4 7 7 7
n=4
m=5
k=3

Output :- Max Sum= 26
Explanations:- (8+9+9)
              second row has the largest sum window with size 3.
```

I gave the brute force approach for traversing all directions(8) along with sliding window approach to calculate the max sum.

Unfortunately I was rejected and I still don't find the optimized solution for the problem made by the interviewer.

**My code that I made-**

(ignore the inputs required)

```
class sliding {
    public static void main(int ar[][], int k) {
        int m = ar.length;
        int n = ar[0].length;
        int sum = 0;

        if (m >= k) { //for row-wise max window
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                int tempSum = 0;
                int x = 0;
                int j = 0;
                while (j < n) {
                    tempSum += ar[i][j];
                    if (j - x + 1 < k)
                        j++;
                    else if (j - x + 1 == k) {
                        sum = Math.max(tempSum, sum);
                        tempSum = tempSum - ar[i][x];
                        x++;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (n >= k) //for column-wise max window
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int tempSum = 0;
                int x = 0;
                int j = 0;
                while (j < m) {
                    tempSum += ar[i]][j];
                if (j - x + 1 < k)
                    j++;
                else if (j - x + 1 == k) {
                    sum = Math.max(tempSum, sum);
                    temSum = tempSum - ar[i][x];
                    x++;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //for diagonal-wise max
    if (n >= k && m >= k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                int x = 0;
                int p = i;
                int q = j;
                int p_initial = p;
                int q_initial = q;
                int tempSum = 0;
                while (p <= m - k && q <= n - k) {
                    if (x < k) {
                        tempSum += ar[p++][q++];
                        x++;
                    } else if (x == k) {
                        sum = Math.max(tempSum, sum);
                        tempSum -= ar[p_initial][q_initial];
                        p_initial++;
                        q_initial++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}// sum variable will store the final answer
```

**Complexity - O(n^3)**

**Can someone optimize my approach or give better solution.**

Comment: What is a "fixed window k" ? Traverse: from where to where ? Your explanations are barely intelligible.

Comment: 8 directions? I might lack imagination, but with left-right, up-down, and the two diagonals, I only count 4

Comment: Negative values allowed?

Comment: @trincot yes negative values are allowed

Comment: @YvesDaoust fixed window means that K consecutive numbers in any possible direction

Comment: Can different directions be combined, or all k consecutive values should be on a straight line?

Comment: @trincot no it cannot be combined the consecutive K numbers should be linear i.e. either vertically or horizontally or diagonally.

Comment: How much is K ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust k is a variable size window

Comment: I know, but that does not tell anything about the value.

Comment: The complexity of the row-wise and column-wise loops is O(n²), and this is optimal. The diagonal-wise loops should be O(n²) as well, this is where the problem lies. There is no need for a triple loop. Also think that there are two distinct diagonal directions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the max subsequence linearly.

Given the sequence `2 3 4 5 2` with `k=3` start from `2 3 4` with `sum=9` and using two indexes - one pointing to `2` and one pointing to `4` - forward them modifying the `sum` accordingly:

- Step 1: `sum=9-2+5=12`
- Step 2: `sum=12-3+2=11`

This allows you to select the `max` linearly, which is much better than having a `n²` brute force solution

Comment: I used this sliding window approach to find the maximum sum but I had to travel 8 directions thus I used brute force there, could you please help me out in finding maximum sum linearly in 2d matrix

Comment: So you didn't implement a brute-force algorithm. What complexity analysis did you give?

Comment: yes I used brute force loops to travel row wise, column wise and 2 diagonal wise and storing the max answer in a variable. Thus I had to use sliding window approach 4 times for row, column and diagonals. My interviewer replied this is not the optimized approach.

Comment: When you were asked for complexity, what did you answer?

Comment: `O(n²)` (or `O(nk)` more precisely) approach is to sum for every cell the next `k` elements. With sliding window for every cell you subtract and add one unit: this is `O(n)`. If you told `n²`, or coded in a `n²` way, maybe the interviewer didn't properly understood your idea of sliding the array, and correctly (imho) rejected you. (here `n` means the total number of cells, that is `n*m`)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: please show your code, we do not understand what you call "brute force" precisely.

Comment: @Jack I mentioned my code with complexity O(N^3) please help me to optimize it

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have mentioned my code above have a read and see if you could find a better solution

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri This answer tells you how to implement it in O(n); what part is not clear?

Comment: @Jack can you provide me the code for your approach

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri no. But you can tell me if something is not clear and I'll try to make it clearer

Comment: @Jack I am not clear for the diagonal traversal part can you help me for diagonal traversal

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri just play with indexes and treat a diagonal as a straight line.. i.e. `rowIdx++; colIdx--;`

Answer (score 0):

To cover the main diagonal direction, use the indexings `ar[i+j][j]` instead of `ar[i][j]`. Make sure to cover the whole matrix, while ensuring `0≤i+j<n` and `0≤j<m`. For a given `j`, `-j≤i<n-j` so that the outer for loop is on `-m<i<n`. The the inner while loop is on `max(0,-i)≤j<min(n-i,n)`.

The inner while loop keeps a similar structure and the process is still `O(nm)`.

The second diagonal is with `ar[i-j][j]`.

Comment: I liked your approach can you please mention the code for diagonal traversal only for your indexing so that it is more easy for me....

Answer (score -1):

```
public int findMaximumSum(int[][] matrix, int key) {
    int y = matrix.length - 1, x = matrix[0].length - 1;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
        for (int i1 = 0, j = key - 1; j <= x; j++, i1++) {
            int sum = matrix[i][i1] + matrix[i][j] + matrix[i][(i1 + j) / 2];
            max = Math.max(max, sum);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: I want diagonal sum as well not only row sum

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).